# The output of this question is correct but i am getting a segmentation error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve the program of array rotation. I am getting segmentation error in the code. Can someone please tell where is the problem in this code?

this is the question

Given an unsorted array arr[] of size N, rotate it by D elements (clockwise).

The first line of the input contains T denoting the number of testcases. First line of each test case contains two space separated elements, N denoting the size of the array and an integer D denoting the number size of the rotation. Subsequent line will be the N space separated array elements.

and i have solved it with the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* rotate(int ar[],int n, int m)
{static int temp[100];
 for(int i =0;i<m;i++)
 {
        temp[i]=ar[i];
    }
    for(int j =m;j<n;j++)
    {
        ar[j-m]=ar[j];
    }
    int x=0;
    for(int k =n-m;k<n;k++)
    {   
        ar[k]=temp[x];
        x++;
    }
   return ar; 
}


int main() {
    //code
    
    int t, n , m;
    cin>>t;
    while(t>0)
    {
        cin>>n>>m;
        int arr[n];
        int * ptr;
        for(int i = 0 ;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
        
        ptr=rotate(arr,n,m);
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        cout<<ptr[j]<<" ";
        
        cout<<endl;
        
        t--;
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are the constrains here ? are you sure `n` is always going to be less than 100(size of temp) ?

Comment: `int arr[n];` = recipe for disaster for online challenges with potentially large data sets. And besides, VLAs aren't C++ standard. Don't use them. use a `std::vector<int> arr(n);` Likewise for `temp` in `rotate`. And if this really is an online thing, any particular reason you're not just using [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) ? I would think that would reduce your code to damn near nothing. That wheel was invented a long time ago.

Comment: Side note`static int temp[100];` don't use static here. It's bad practice (introduces global state)

Comment: Apart from the use of VLAs (not valid C++), the most obvious explanation is that your code is accessing eleemts past the end of one of the arrays.    For whatever input you are supplying, you need to step through with a debugger.   Of particular note, you need check EVERY index before using it to access/modify an element of an array.

Comment: You should provide input that triggers the error.  Then compile the code with debug output, run the crashing code through a debugger and tell us where it dies.  If n is too large, the stack size (say, 8k) will not be large enough to hold your arr variable.  Also, you should help yourself and people here by formatting your code (for instance, cout after for statement should be indented).

Comment: @WhozCraig `temp` in `rotate` isn't VLA: `int temp[100]`.

Comment: @bloody Never said it was. It also isn't a `std::vector<int>`, which was the point in the first place.

Comment: Also, problem description and code should use the same variable names to make it easier to figure out what is going (D in problem is m in code).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you , I am a beginner and i don't know much about the inbuilt functions and classes.

Answer (score 0):

If m > n then it crashes in the first for() loop in rotate as you index past the end of arr.

If m < 0 it crashes in the 2nd loop as it index before arr.

There are probably more cases.